# I have a message: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  SELECT *
  FROM tableA 
  WHERE  (( typec = "red"
            AND cl = "1er", "2e", "3e", "4e"));
```

I have a message: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) Mysql

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator compares two singular values. If you want to compare a list of values, you can use the `in` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tableA 
WHERE  typec = 'red' AND
       cl IN ('1er', '2e', '3e', '4e');
-- Here --^
```